# How to detect swipe in a parent view having UIScrollView as a subview?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, gesture

I have 3 nested views, Main view (parent) -> UIScrollView -> ImageView. 
I am building a content viewer, where a user swipes to get the next/previous image from a list. But i want this next image to load only after the user has reached either the rightmost/bottom(end of the image) or the leftmost/top corner. There is a transition animation involved, where in the next/previous image follows the swipe while loading the next item.
How should I go about achieving this?

P.S.:I have already tried adding gesture recognizers in the parent view, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using the scrollview to move the current image around and then when the user encounters either of the two trigger points (left-top/right-bottom) you want to trigger your animation and load in the next image. If that is the case, why don't you just use the scrollView delegate method `-scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scroller`? In that method you can check the scrollView's `contentOffset` property and compare it against the current image's dimensions. When the `contentOffset` falls within your parameters for triggering the animation and load, do so.

Comment: Yes, I could do that. I tried adding a delegate to the panGestureRecognizer to recognize swipe gestures if it reaches the end of the image. 
Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Swipe Gestures

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe_left = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipe_left)];
    swipe_left.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [yourView addGestureRecognizer:swipe_left];
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe_right = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipe_right)];
    swipe_right.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [yourView addGestureRecognizer:swipe_right];

-(void)swipe_left
{
    //Write your content offset if required
}


-(void)swipe_right
{

   someView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(470, 0);      //Example
}
```

Regards

Deepak

Happy New Year!!

Comment: I have already tried adding gesture recognizers in the main view. But the scrollview is eating away all the gestures.